How to solve $AX=B$ for $X$ if $A$ is not invertible?
How to determine the matrix $X$ that satisfies the following equation?
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 5 & -3 \\ 2 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
X=\begin{bmatrix} 10 & 2 & 7 \\4 & 1 & 3 \\-2 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm trying to solve it using the general equations which
$Ax=B $,
$x=A^{-1}B$
So I need to find the inverse of $A$, firstly i'm trying to find $\det(A)$ using Sarrus method and I got $\det(A)=0$.
$|A|= (5\cdot2\cdot1)+(5\cdot-1\cdot-1)+(-3\cdot2\cdot-1)-(-3\cdot2\cdot-1)-(5\cdot-1\cdot-1)-(5\cdot2\cdot1)$
$|A|=10+5+6-6-5-10$
$|A|=0$
Because of that, I can't find the inverse of the matrix $A$.

Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
here,
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

@Angelo im trying to find x

I can't quite parse your question. I understand the two $3 \times 3$ matrices, but which is which? Is one $A$ and one $B$? You have =X= in between them; are you saying both are equal to $X$? And if so, how do you account for the matrices being different? Is $X$ the same as $x$? What is $x$ and/or $X$? Is it a vector, a matrix, or something else? When you write Ax=B x = A^-1.B, is the period some kind of multiplication, or the beginning of a new sentence? I could help format your question, if only I could understand it.

@TheoBendit i'm sorry, im just edited it

@Mirna, you should write in your question what you tried in order to solve your problem, otherwise your post will be closed by moderators very soon. Read this thread and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Moreover, you should learn to use MathJax in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

If $X_1$ is the first column of $X$, then$$\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 5 & -3 \ 2 & 2 & -1 \ -1 & -1 &1\end{bmatrix}X_1=\begin{bmatrix} 10 \4 \-2 \end{bmatrix},$$where the right hand side is the first column of the $3 \times 3$ matrix that was on the right hand side. This is just a standard $Ax=b$ matrix equation, that can be solved with an augmented matrix. Try the same for other columns. If you can find solutions for these columns, put them together to get $X$. If any of the equations turn out not to be consistent, then there will be no such $X$. Note: since $\det A = 0$, $X$ will not be unique.

@Ang, unlikely to be closed by moderators, but could well be closed by votes of five users. Mirna, do you know how to solve $Ax=b$ when $x,b$ are vectors, if $A$ isn't invertible? Using row operations? Do the same for $AX=B$.

@Theo bandit we can assume $X_1$ to be a $3×1$ matrix, containing $a_{11},a_{21},a_{31}$, then $a_{31}$ will have 3 fixed values, while $a_{11}$ and $a_{21}$ can have any real value. Is this true?

@Gwen Yes, with the proviso that $a_{11} = -a_{21}$. Only one of the variables is free.

$$A\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}5x+5y-3z&=a\\2x+2y-z&=b\\-x-y+z&=c\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}z&=c+x+y\\x+y-c&=b\\2x+2y-3c&=a\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}y&=b+c-x\\z&=b+2c\\a-2b+c&=0.\end{cases}$$
Each of the three columns of $B$ satisfies the compatibility condition $a-2b+c=0$, hence there exists a solution $X$, and its corresponding column is of the form $\begin{pmatrix}t\\b+c-t\\b+2c\end{pmatrix}$. The general solution is therefore:
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}t&u&v\\2-t&1-u&2-v\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Just write down the $9$ linear equations in the $9$ variables of $X$ from the equation $AX=B$. If the first row of $X$ is given by $(a,b,c)$, then the remaining $6$ variables can be expressed by $a,b,c$, and
all solutions are given by
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \cr 2-a & 1-b & 2-c \cr 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
